# Why "Activecell is Selection" is false when there is only one cell selected?

Tags: excel, vba, selection

The `Activecell Is Selection` statement should be TRUE when there is only one cell selected. Could someone tell me why it is FALSE?

Comment: "statement should be TRUE1 why ? The Is operator determines if two object references refer to the same object. Maybe you want `activecell.address = selection.address`

Comment: @Cdp _The Is operator determines if two object references refer to the same object._ when a single cell is selected `Activecell` and `Selection` do both refer to the same object. The OPs question is given that, why does the test return False.

Comment: @uno I can't answer the Why.  Given that that test doesn't give the result you expect, can you tell us what you are trying to achieve,  we might be able to give you an alternative

Comment: @chris  Try this `debug.print cells(1,1) is cells(1,1)`

Comment: I would guess that the two properties both return a `Range` object which share the same address, but are not internally referencing the same object.

Comment: The goal is to determine if the selected range is a single cell. I thought this would be enough, but I see that it will not:
`IsCell = Selection Is ActiveCell`
The explanation is, as Tim Williams says that Activecell and Selection are two different objects even though they point to the same cell.
Therefore you have to use the addresses:
`IsCell = (Selection.Address = activeCell.Address)`

Answer (score 2):

Both `ActiveCell` and `Selection` return a `Range` object which in this case represent the same cell, but they are *not the same VBA object* even though they share the same properties.

```vb
Sub Tester()

    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range
    
    Set r1 = Selection
    Set r2 = ActiveCell
    Debug.Print r1.Address, r2.Address, r1 Is r2   '> $D$11   $D$11   False
    
    'this is the same thing but assigned differently...
    Set r1 = [D11]
    Set r2 = [D11]
    Debug.Print r1.Address, r2.Address, r1 Is r2  '> $D$11   $D$11   False
    
    Set r2 = r1 'now they refer to the same [VBA] object
    Debug.Print r1.Address, r2.Address, r1 Is r2  '> $D$11   $D$11   True

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

I think we have to compare the full address:
ActiveCell.Address(External:=True)=Selection.Address(External:=True)

Comment: Given the context (i.e. ActiveCell and Selection), using full address has no advantages over simply using `.Address` (as covered in the first comment to the OP). So this answer only serves to confuse and/or add to testing time. Please consider testing your own hypothesis before posting.